# Access is denied when I am executing an update query with Ucanaccess

Tags: java, jdbc, ucanaccess

I have just started with ucanaccess and I am attempting to work out how it works. I wanted to update my Access database's username from "Sutaciba" to "Evan" but it shows the following error:

"Exception occured: 
UCAExc:::4.0.4 C:\Users\evanc\AppData\Roaming\IT PAT DataBase (Access is denied)".

Seems like Ucanaccess doesn't have permission to gain access to my database for some reason.

Thank you for any help!

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    int ID = 1;
    String username = "Sutachiba";
    String password = "Evanchui123";
    String email = "evanchui34@gmail.com";

   try
    {
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\evanc\\AppData\\Roaming\\IT PAT DataBase");
      Statement s = conn.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT [username], [password] FROM [tblUser] WHERE ID =" + ID);
      while(rs.next())
      {
          username = rs.getString(1);
          password = rs.getString(2);
          email = rs.getString(3);
          System.out.println("Username: " + username + '\n' + "Password: " + '\n' + "Email:" + email);
      }

      String newN = "Evan";
      String updateQuery = "UPDATE userDB SET (username) = (?) WHERE ID =" + ID;

      PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(updateQuery);
      st.setString(1, newN);
      st.executeUpdate();
      System.out.println("Successfully updated userdata!");

      conn.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.err.println("Exception occured: ");
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: The filespec in your connection URL does not include the file extension (.accdb or .mdb).

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what happened to it! :D